# datetime problem when subtracting a month

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using csv and datetime to subtract one month to a date and send a remainder email on due dates. Code works but I know that there is a better solution than mine.

Code where I'm having problems is when domain expiration date is month 01 (so with my code 01 - 1 = 0 and not 12 (December):

```
with open('Domains.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        X, DOMAIN, EXPIRE, OWNER, REGISTRANT, HOSTING = row
        print(EXPIRE[0:7])
        if (int(EXPIRE[5:7]) - 1) == int(now.strftime('%m')):  # Months from 02 to 12
            print('Sent renew mail to: ' + DOMAIN)
        elif (int(EXPIRE[5:7]) - 1) == 0 and  int(now.strftime('%m')) == 12: # Expires on month 01
            print('Sent renew mail to: ' + DOMAIN)
        else:
           continue
```

My csv data is like this:

```
X,DOMAIN,EXPIRE,OWNER,REGISTRANT,HOSTING
A,domain2.com,2020-11-07,Own,A2HOSTING,A2HOSTING
B,company.com,2021-02-13,Customer,SITEGROUND,SITEGROUND
```

Comment: assuming `now` is a datetime object, why not use the month attribute? `now.month` instead of `int(now.strftime('%m'))`

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at `datetime` library and use  datetime.strptime(EXPIRE,"%Y-%m-%d") to parse the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you are trying to send a message one month before the domains expiry date.

Why not do something like this, The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library takes care of all edge cases, and makes its much easier to work with dates

```
from datetime import datetime
EXPIRE="2020-09-07"


ExpireDate = datetime.strptime(EXPIRE,"%Y-%m-%d")
if (ExpireDate-datetime.now()).days < 30:
    print('Sent renew mail')
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: I will try first this option just with datetime. Later I can try using pandas

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that are better suited for this than using the CSV reader. In particular, the `pandas` package is excellent for representing tabular data and includes support for datetime manipulations. You can read in the data and convert the `EXPIRE` data from strings into `datetime` objects as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('Domains.csv')
dates = pd.to_datetime(data['EXPIRE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note the `format` argument, which is used to tell `pandas` how to interpret the datetime as a string. You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

You can now separate out the dates based on conditionals:

```py
# Months from 02 to 12
expire_02_12 = dates[(dates.dt.month >= 2) & (dates.dt.month <= 12)]
print(expire_02_12)
```

The `dt` attribute is used so that you can access the standard datetime attributes like `month`, `day`, etc.

Notice how this approach does not use a `for` loop but relies on array manipulations instead (If you're curious, pandas is using `NumPy` for a lot of this behind the scenes). This makes it much faster for larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really taking full advantage of what the `datetime` module offers — specifically the ability to create `date` objects which know all the rules about how they work, days in each month, etc, and instances of the `timedelta` class which represent durations of time (such as 30 days).

Here's how to use these facilities to solve to your problem (and simplify your code). i.e. A `datatime` object is created from the `EXPIRE` field of each row, and a 30 day `timedelta` is subtracted from it. Note there are no "edge" cases to deal with manually.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


with open('Domains.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)

    for (X, DOMAIN, EXPIRE, OWNER, REGISTRANT, HOSTING) in csv_reader:
        expire_date = datetime.strptime(EXPIRE,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
        notice_date = expire_date - timedelta(days=30)
        print('Send renew mail to: {} on {}'.format(DOMAIN, notice_date))
```

Output with sample data:

```
Send renew mail to: domain2.com on 2020-10-08
Send renew mail to: company.com on 2021-01-14
```